# Get the previous URI in laravel/php

Tags: php, laravel-4, uri

Searching on the web i found that the URI class in laravel 4 was moved to Request::path();

I looked hard on laravel docs, but i didn't find what i was looking for.

So how to get the uri from the page we are coming from in laravel 4 if URI::previous() is no more possible?

Comment: `Request::server('HTTP_REFERER')` helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45713501/470749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Laravel 4 `URL::previous()` does the magic. The method just looks up the HTTP referer from `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.

But heads up, be aware that (from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)):

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the
>   current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will
>   set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a
>   feature. In short, **it cannot really be trusted**.

Comment: You're right, for some strange reason URL::previous() didn't work and i ended up using http_referer, but now previous() work too!