# How to get the http referer in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, http-referer

I'm trying to get the Referer of my users. Like if they come from facebook, youtube, google or anything else.

Now I've tried something like that:

```php
$referrer = $this->request->headers->get('referer');
$url = $referrer ? $this->to($referrer) : $this->getPreviousUrlFromSession();
return $url ?: $this->to('/'); // returns: Method referer does not exist.
```

This:

```php
return $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] // returns Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER
```

that:

```php
session_start();
    
if ( !isset( $_SESSION["origURL"] ) ) {
    $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; // returns Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER
}
```

But nothing worked like expected.

Does someone know a solution how I can check the referer?

I need that because I want to check if the user comes from some specific URL's and if so, I want to give the user some extra "clicks" to rank up. Something like a small affiliate system.

Comment: Be aware - the referrer is subject to the client announcing it truthfully... it is not reliable in a "true" sense.

Answer (score 46):

Laravel way of getting referer:

```php
request()->headers->get('referer');
```

Answer (score 42):

It seems like this will do what you are looking for :

```
Request::server('HTTP_REFERER').
```

You can read the Api DOC here :

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_server

Comment: I've tried that out but this returns allways "null"

Comment: @PHPprogrammer42 Then there probably isn't a referer sent.

Comment: This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.

Comment: mhh.. so what would you do, to check if the user klicked a link like: "http://mywebsite.com/unicorn/1111111 -- Without coming from my website itself? So I can give the "thread" with the id 1111111 some extra clicks

Comment: 404 on the link, here is the good one: https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_server

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `request()` helper:

```php
request()->headers->get('referer');
```

or the `Request` facade:

```php
Request::header('referer');
Request::server('HTTP_REFERER'); // same thing as above
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use url() helper

```php
url()->previous();
```

If you want to go back to the page that initialise the request, we simply write this (usually in the controller):

```php
return redirect()->back();
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get `Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER` is because not all requests have a `HTTP_REFERER` header, only most of the requests that come from other websites. If you visit a website directly with the url, you wont be sending a `HTTP_REFERER` header.

So, you should check if the header is set first.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["origURL"]) && array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER', $_SERVER))
    $_SESSION["origURL"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Comment: well that works fine if I come from facebook. I mostly want to check if the user comes from whatsapp. If I post the URL that redirects to this code, I only get "null". Maybe it's because whatsapp is a app, not a website. But if I look into my logs, I can see that the referer is https://chat.whatsapp.com/ -- strange

Comment: I get log files of a specific statistic programm that I use on my website. There I can see some user data like IP, browser, referer etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::get('/send', function (Request $request) { 
    echo $request->headers->get('referer');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's up to the client to send the referrer information int he HTTP request's header.

So if the client (browser, app, etc.) doesn't send the referrer, it won't be available to the server in the request headers. I guess the WhatsApp app has disabled sending the referrer, so there is no way to get it.

In some browsers, sending of the referrer information can be turned off in the settings or with a extension. It is also easily spoofed with `curl` for instance, so it cannot be relied on as a security measure.

More info in my answer here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050268/does-document-referrer-equal-the-http-referer-header/49050494](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49050268/does-document-referrer-equal-the-http-referer-header/49050494#49050494)

If your unsure about the client sending the referrer, it's easy to check it with JavaScript (referrer is spelled here differently from the HTTP header, to add to the confusion):

```
console.log(
    document.referrer
);
```