# Laravel 8: Redirect in route, preserving one parameter

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to redirect to route with name doug-test, but I want to preserve the url parameter.  I saw a webpage that says use $request->query('url') to get the url parameter, but that doesn't seem to work.  I want to know the value of the *get* parameter "url".

For example, if someone goes /login?url=/xyz

I want them redirected to /dougs-page?url=/xyz  where /dougs-page is a route named "doug-test"

Here's what I have so far:

```
Route::get('/login', function (Request $request) {return redirect()->route('doug-test', ['url'=> $request->query('url')]);})->middleware('not-auth')->name('login');
```

The error I'm getting is "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::query()"

Comment: you don't typehint the facade `Request` as you don't want an instance of a facade as it is a static proxy for another object ... if you want an instance of something you want the actual `Request` class (`Illuminate\Http\Request`) which the facade is a proxy for. ... https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/facades#facade-class-reference

Comment: @lagbox I don't totally understand how you are saying the code should look.  Are you saying take out the class name "Request" ?

Comment: you are aliasing the wrong `Request` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind.  Taking a closer look at [the docs for Request,](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Request.html) I see query() is a static method.  This works:

```
Route::get('/login', function (Request $request) {return redirect()->route('doug-test', ['url'=> $request::query('url')]);})->middleware('not-auth')->name('login');
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this one answers your question. [How to get the http referer in laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45713409/how-to-get-the-http-referer-in-laravel)

`url()->previous();`

Comment: Thanks, but not really.  I'm asking a different question.  Just generally, I want to get one parameter from the current request

Comment: Do you want the original URL the user is requesting before they are redirected? When you say parameter, I think of URL query parameters that would be passed from a form, like `example.com/?name=joe`, but I don't think that is what you mean.

Comment: url just happens to be the name of a parameter here, it could be any parameter name with any value.  I just want to redirect and save a parameter value.  I just added a clarification to question.   And, yes, I mean URL parameters.  Although, I figured out what was wrong.